# How to access asp_membership data using MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm new in MVC , i have a database it has Asp_membership databse for creating roles and login . i'm trying to validate the user login through MVC membership controls but unable to connect my database, i changed web.config also

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="sampleCompanyEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Encrypted" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Can you please guide how i validate the my database using membership controls  in MVC5

hear is the sample code i'm using

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        if(Membership.ValidateUser("admin",model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1)
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
        return View(model);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below .Net Articles for Membership login.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Add membership DB table into your database.